# "Since leaving" vs "since he left"

Tags: difference

What's the difference between the meaning of the following sentences:

> 1. Since leaving** school, he has had three jobs
> 2. Since he left** school, he has had three jobs.

Do they mean the same thing being different in terms of the sentence structure?

source http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/since

Comment: They're equivalent (though the second would be better as "Since he *left* school" - not *has left*). The second has a candidate substitution of since=because, but it doesn't make much sense, so we can discard it.

Comment: @Lawrence, sorry to have posted wrong,I have now edited

Comment: No problem - they're the example sentences that *you* are asking about. :)

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Since+leaving+school%2C+since+he+left+school&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CSince%20leaving%20school%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csince%20he%20left%20school%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both constructions are correct and convey the same meaning;  for usage of "***[since](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/since)***" followed by gerund see the following extract:

> - We can use since + -ing form to refer to time when the subject of the verb is the same in the main clause and the subordinate clause:
>
>   - ***Since leaving school***, he has had three or four temporary jobs. (***Since he left school***, he has …)
>   - ***Since moving from a Chicago suburb*** to southern California a few months ago, I’ve learned how to play a new game called Lanesmanship. (***Since I moved*** …, I’ve learned …)

Cambridge Dictionary

Comment: Your answer is exactly the same to the one which I have made this question from.Actually the source of my question.It won't help me.

Comment: @yubrajsharma - what is that you don't understand?